# find count of messages foreachRDD in JavaDStream

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Hi i am trying to integrate Kafka with Spark streaming.

I want to find count of messages foreachRDD in JavaDStream.

Please find the below code and give me some suggestions.

```
public class App {

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("Streamingkafka")
            .setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(1000));

    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("data_one");

    JavaPairInputDStream<String,String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
    JavaDStream<String> msgDataStream = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
       @Override
       public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
         return tuple2._2();
       }
     });
 msgDataStream.print();
 msgDataStream.count();

  ssc.start();            
  ssc.awaitTermination();  
  }

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        JavaDStream<String> msgDataStream = directKafkaStream.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
               @Override
               public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
                 return tuple2._2();
               }
             });

    msgDataStream.foreachRDD(x -> System.out.println(x.count()));           
      ssc.start();            
      ssc.awaitTermination();
```

I'm doing foreachRDD in lambda way.If you are using previous version of java, use the below foreach code .

```
msgDataStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {

            @Override
            public void call(JavaRDD<String> arg0) throws Exception {

                System.out.println(arg0.count());

            }
        }

        );
```